# Can envoy route based on ip range?

Tags: envoyproxy

I want envoy to dns lookup hostname and route request based on resolved ip range. For example, a hostname x.internal.com resolves to 10.0.0.1, which is internal because it's in range 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255. So x.internal.com will be routed to cluster-a. And host resolves to other ranges will be routed to cluster-b. Is this possible? I looked through docs and I don't think it is supported. I would like to hear other people's thoughts.

I looked through envoy docs. I expect this doesn't work.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by playing with `virtual_hosts` and `domains` in your Envoy config.

For the example, let's say:

- we have 2 clusters:

  - `clusterA` for internal traffic (`*.internal.mydomain.com`)
  - `clusterB` for other traffic (`*.mydomain.com`)
- both clusters will listen on ports `5000`, and answer on `/`:

  - `clusterA` will return `Hello from clusterA`
  - `clusterB` will return `Hello from clusterB`
- Envoy will be listening on port `8080`

In that case, the following minimal envoy config should work. The important part for you is `route_config.virtual_hosts` under the `envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager` filter.

```yaml
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: envoy_listener
    address:
      socket_address:
        protocol: TCP
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8080
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: routes
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: a
              domains:
              - "*.internal.mydomain.com"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: "clusterA"
            - name: b
              domains:
              - "*.mydomain.com"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: "clusterB"
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
  - name: clusterA
    type: STRICT_DNS
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: clusterA
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: cluster_a
                port_value: 5000
  - name: clusterB
    type: STRICT_DNS
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: clusterB
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: cluster_b
                port_value: 5000
```

As you can see here:

```yaml
route_config:
  name: routes
  virtual_hosts:
  - name: a
    domains:
    - "*.internal.mydomain.com"
    routes:
    - match:
        prefix: "/"
      route:
        cluster: "clusterA"
  - name: b
    domains:
    - "*.mydomain.com"
    routes:
    - match:
        prefix: "/"
      route:
        cluster: "clusterB"
```

Depending on the `host`, envoy will redirect either to `clusterA` or `clusterB`. You can verify this by calling envoy with an internal or non-internal host:

```bash
$ curl -H "Host: xxx.internal.mydomain.com" localhost:8080
Hello from clusterA

$ curl -H "Host: xxx.mydomain.com" localhost:8080
Hello from clusterB
```

This has been tested on Envoy v1.27.0.

Comment: Thanks I understand. But I have domain name that points to both internal and external. For example, it can be a.example.com is internal and b.example.com is external. I guess the only way is to distinguish them manually and write static route rules like you pointed.

Comment: Ok I see. It should work the same; if you have hosts like `a.example.com`, `b.example.com`, then you can specify them in the `domains` list, instead of the regex with `*`.

Comment: You should also be able to play with a [Lua filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.27.0/configuration/http/http_filters/lua_filter) to do a DNS resolution inside that filter, and add something like a header to redirect to the right cluster. But that's extra complexity; if you know the domains, it'd be better to just add them statically in the envoy config.